# AutoHotKey ImageSearch not working with multiple image files

Tags: image, autohotkey

I am trying to implement an ImageSearch feature in a script I've written. It works when I hard code a specific image path, but does not work when I try and loop through the images in a folder labelled image1,image2,image3,etc... This technique is apparently what works for other people based on some examples I've seen.

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
CoordMode, Mouse, Pixel
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1

^!6::
CoordMode, Pixel, Mouse
CoordMode, ToolTip
var = 0
Loop {

    var += 1

    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, *75 C:\Users\User\Desktop\image%varx%.jpg

    ;This would work if the other was commented out
    ;ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, *75 C:\Users\User\Desktop\image1.jpg

    If (ErrorLevel = 0) {
        SoundPlay, C:\Users\User\Desktop\found.wav
        ToolTip, Found, %FoundX%, %FoundY%
        ;Click, %FoundX%, %FoundY%
        ErrorLevel := -1
        FoundX := ""
        FoundY := ""
        Sleep 5000

    }
    If ErrorLevel {
        ToolTip, Didn't find image%var%.jpg, 0, 25
        Sleep 1000
    }
    If var = 8
        var = 0
}
Return




Esc:: ExitApp
```

Comment: You're incrementing `var` but calling `varx`. Change one to the other and you should be set.

Comment: Wow. That's why I need an IDE. Do you happen to also know why it only works when I select certain windows? I have 4 equally sized windows. 3 of which I'm searching in and 1 of which I code in. When I click in the Sublime Text window to edit the code, the search stops. I thought I had it just scanning the entire screen.

Comment: FWIW, I use notepad exclusively for AHK. `CoordMode` isn't setup properly, so I'm guessing that might be your issue there. The third parameter must be one of these: `Screen` (default if blank), `Relative`, `Window`, or `Client`. Also, if you have a multi-monitor setup, note that `A_ScreenWidth` and `A_ScreenHeight` are the dimensions of only your primary monitor and not your entire display.